# How to get Broadcast receiver notifications for a day and time in calender in Android?

Tags: android, calendar, broadcastreceiver, dayofweek

I am working on an app that will notify the user when it is a Friday at 9:00am to do certain action, so this is gonna be a reminder only. However, I could not find many information or tutorials about the day event of a calendar in broadcast receiver, any suggestions?

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked into using an AlarmManager:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

You can use it to schedule notifications in your code.